# How did Iron Man subdue The Hulk in Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-age-of-ultron

The fight in the film was really awesome but I just assumed it would end with Black Widow showing up to calm Hulk down since Hulk is supposed to have limitless strength and become more powerful as he gets more angry.

Since Black Widow was incapacitated by the Scarlet Witch I thought Hulk would surely just thrash the Hulkbuster then run off but instead the fight cuts off and in the next scene they're on the jet with Bruce Banner shivering and Stark looking mildly pleased with himself as if he was somehow able to subdue him.

How did he do this? Does this mean the movie Hulk has far more limited power than in the comic books?

Comment: I had to downvote. We see the entire fight on-screen, with Iron Man clearly knocking Hulk out at the end. Not entirely believable, but obviously in the MCU Hulkbuster Armor > Hulk.

Comment: Hulk was knocked out by a liquid spray. Watch it again. This is already asked and answered at this other link: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92225/what-did-veronica-spray-on-hulk-in-age-of-ultron

Comment: @omegacron The hulkbuster suit was not what took out the hulk. It eas a spray. See link in my preceding comment above.

Answer (score 3):

We know that in this scene, The Hulk's rampage is triggered by Scarlet Witch messing with his brain, indicated by his somewhat reddish eyes. Over the course of the fight, he is clearly out of control and attacking anything or anyone that gets in his way - quite unlike how we see him act in *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*, [where he seems to be able to prioritise targets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91684/why-is-the-hulk-so-angry/91698#91698).

After a certain part of the fight between The Hulk and the Hulkbuster suit, we see that The Hulk seems to be dazed, or somewhat confused - we see a shot or two of him seemingly "coming too", his face showing what could be concern or sadness about the destruction he has caused as he sees people running and buildings collapsing. At this stage in the fight, his eyes appear to have gone back to normal.

We have seen from *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* that "cognitive re-calibration" (hitting someone really hard in the head) is enough to stop someone from being under mind control. It is my belief that the same thing happened here, at which point The Hulk began to revert back into Bruce Banner after one final punch from the Hulkbuster armour subdued him completely.

It is also worth mentioning that at one point in the fight scene we see the Hulkbuster suit seem to spray some kind of chemical on The Hulk, [which may or may not have contributed to his defeat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92317/24087).

Additionally, I think it is safe to say that the movie version of The Hulk has more limited power than the one seen in the comics, based on what we have seen so far in *The Incredible Hulk*, *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, most of which have him being subdued in ways which would not usually affect The Hulk in the comics.

Comment: If anyone has screengrabs from *Avengers: Age of Ultron* showing The Hulk's eyes while red, and then later normal again, please add them to my answer. I am still looking.